# Huge VBA Function problems

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that will take data inputted from a job and create an executive summary in MS Word. I have programmed in all of the code required to get the numbers and verbiage correct in the word document, but the VBA Function is too large.

Is there a way I can split it up in to several smaller Functions that all execute with one button in excel?

Edit. As recommended below I have set the following.

```
Sub LazyEngineer()

Call Master
Call data
Call data1
Call data2
Call data3

End Sub

Sub Master()

    Dim appWD As Word.Application

    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWD.Visible = True
    appWD.Documents.Add
    Myfilename = appWD.ActiveDocument.Name
    appWD.PrintPreview = True
    With appWD.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom
        .PageColumns = 1
        .PageRows = 1
    End With
    'header
  -- lots of other code to make this thing type a report --
 End Sub

Sub data()
 '1
     If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b31") > 0 Then
         .TypeText "    Stage "
         .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b5")
         .TypeParagraph
         .TypeText " The well had an initial pressure of "
         .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b7")
         .TypeText "psi."
         .TypeText " The well broke down at "
         .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("job Data").Range("b11")
         .TypeText "psi at "
         .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b12")
         .TypeText "bpm, a total of "
         .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b31")
         .TypeText " clean bbls of fluid was pumped. The Treatment was pumped to completion."
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("job Data").Range("A28") > 0 Then
            .TypeText "The total amount of proppant pumped was "
            .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b28")
            .TypeText " lbs of "
            .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("a28")
            .TypeText ", "
            End If
   If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("job Data").Range("A29") > 0 Then
        .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b29")
            .TypeText " lbs of "
            .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("a29")
            .TypeText ", "
            End If
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("job Data").Range("A30") > 0 Then
        .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b30")
            .TypeText " lbs of "
            .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("a30")
            End If
    .TypeText ". The average pressure and rate were "
    .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("B23")
    .TypeText "psi and "
    .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b24")
    .TypeText "bpm. "
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("B19") > 0 Then
    .TypeText "The Initial ISIP was "
    .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("B19").Text
    .TypeText "psi ("
    .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b20").Text
    .TypeText " psi/ft)."
    End If
    .TypeText " The final ISIP was "
    .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b21").Text
    .TypeText " psi ("
    .TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Data").Range("b22").Text
    .TypeText " psi/ft)."
   End If
    .TypeParagraph
 End Sub

 Sub data1()
  --  Code --
 End Sub

 Sub data2()
  --  Code --
 End Sub

 Sub data3()
  --  Code --
 End Sub
```

It will get as far as running the master Function then throw the following error.  "Compile Error Invalid or unqualified reference"

Hopefully this edit will get my topic back on track and open for help. I will admit to being an amateur with coding.

The code for data repeats itself 10 times with one cell progression for each of the .range instances. in each sub

Thank you to all who have helped.
Rick.

Comment: Create your main macro and split certain items into sub macro's and just call them from your main macro?

Comment: show some of your code as example

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Sub data is highlighted yellow when the error is thrown.

Comment: You need to show the code for `data`

Comment: Code has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, break your main macro up into smaller sections and make sure to declare variables that will be used in multiple `Sub Procedures` at the `Module` level (e.g. at the very top of the `Module` outside of any `Sub Procedure`).

Next, create a separate `Sub Procedure` to call each new procedure. It can be in the same `Module` or in a different one, but it must stay inside the same `VBA Project`.

```
Sub CallMacros()

Call TheNameOfTheFirstMacroYouWantToCall
Call TheNameOfTheSecondMacroYouWantToCall

'Continue calling the smaller macros until you've called them all.

End Sub
```

Assign the `CallMacros` macro to your button.

Comment: Okay, tried this but still have no success. Is there a way to place my code on here so that others can look at it and get a better idea of what is going on?  I admit that I am an amateur when it comes to this kind of stuff.

Comment: I keep running into the following error. "Compile Error" "Invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: Edit your question to include the relevant pieces of your code. Don't forget to format it as code.